# Calculating $P(A\cap B)$ from $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ without knowing $P(A\mid B)$ or $P(B\mid A)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Is there a way to calculate $P(A\cap B)$ from $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ without knowing $P(A\mid B)$ or $P(B\mid A)$?

I'm asking because it seems to me that a primary function of Bayes' theorem is to calculate $P(B\mid A)$ from $P(A\mid B)$ and $P(B)$ and $P(A)$. However, if one can calculate $P(B\mid A)$ from just $P(B)$ and $P(A)$ without needing $P(A\mid B)$ then Bayes' and indeed the second general multiplication principle would be unnecessary. Is this possible?

I'm talking about conditional probability btw.

Thanks

Comment: No, of course not.  Suppose (1) that $A$ and $B$ are respectively the chance of throwing heads and the chance of throwing tails on a fair coin; then $P(A\text{ and }B)=0$.  Suppose (2) that $A$ and $B$ are respectively the chance of throwing heads and the chance of throwing *heads* on a fair coin;  then $P(A\text{ and }B)=\frac12$. But in both (1) and (2) we have $P(A)=P(B) =\frac12$, so additional information must be required to calculate $P(A\text{ and }B)$.

Comment: No. If $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are known then you can have $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ in case of independence, but also $P(A\cap B)=0$ if $A\cap B=\emptyset$. You can find $P(A\cap B)$ if - next to $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ you also have $P(A\cup B)$. This by $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Only if you knew that $A$ and $B$ are **independent**, you could write $P(A , B) = P(A) P(B)$.  But knowing that is actually also knowing the conditionals, as $A$ and $B$ are independent iff $P(A | B) = P(A)$

In general, $P(A , B)$ has more information than $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ alone: you can obtain the later from the former - eg : $P(A) = \sum_B P(A, B)$ , but not the reverse.